# List creation from dataframe using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

having a dataframe as below:

```
data={'column1':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'person':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'],'location1':['GOA','BANGLORE','GOA','BANGLORE','BANGLORE','DELHI','BANGLORE','DELHII','KOCHI','DELHI','DELHI','KOCHI'],'location2':['BANGLORE','GOA','GOA','BANGLORE','DELHI','DELHI','BANGLORE','BANGLORE','DELHI','KOCHI','DELHI','KOCHI'],'time':[20,40,0,0,34,0,0,23,21,56,0,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: img]

need to create a list of list

[image: img2]

```
for i in set(df.column1):
    for j in set(df.person):
            col=['location1','location2','time']
            print(df[col].values.tolist())
```

But couldn't do the rest. Can anyone help me to create list of list?

Comment: You [shouldn't use an image here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).
What you have provided in your image can be represented as text formatted as code.
You can [edit] your post to make changes.

Comment: Your code is not valid python.  Please make sure your sample code can run first.

Comment: what I mean is that's not a valid dictionary - what is `A` in that?  Shouldn't those be strings?

Comment: A is a string..

Comment: so maybe put some quotes around it?

Comment: I am sorry. can you check the data now. Just learning the code

Comment: can you elaborate on why you want `[[0,20],[40,0]]` and not `[20, 40, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 3):

You can start off by grouping the dataframe based on the columns 'column1', `person` and `location1`. After that, you use `apply` to make a list of the results in every group.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['column1','person','location1'])['time'].apply(lambda x:list(x))

column1  person  location1
1        A       BANGLORE     [40, 0]
                 GOA          [20, 0]
         B       BANGLORE     [34, 0]
                 DELHI        [0, 23]
2        C       DELHI        [56, 0]
                 KOCHI        [21, 0]
Name: time, dtype: object
```

Finally, you perform the same function again.

```
result = grouped_df.groupby(['column1','person']).apply(lambda x:list(x))

column1  person
1        A         [[40, 0], [20, 0]]
         B         [[34, 0], [0, 23]]
2        C         [[56, 0], [21, 0]]
Name: time, dtype: object
```

### Update

To obtain a dataframe of your desired output, just use `reset_index`

```
result.reset_index()

   column1 person                time
0        1      A  [[40, 0], [20, 0]]
1        1      B  [[34, 0], [0, 23]]
2        2      C  [[56, 0], [21, 0]]
```

Comment: i want column1 also on my output.

Comment: can you check that too

Comment: I have updated it. Is this what you need?

Comment: I need the output is in the format as shown in the question. I am trying to create dijikstra algm. I need to prepare the distance matrix. that's what i am trying right now.can you help me? you now i need all the diagonal to zero

Comment: I think this is the dataframe you need. For the algm part, this will be a different topic. You can open a new question after you have finished this part :)

Comment: @MathewJohn Let me know if you need any update on the answer, if not, you can mark this answer. Thanks!